# Display the latest post from a category in a page

Tags: posts, categories

I want to display in page the latest post content from a category.

For example, the category `foo` has the following posts:

- 1. Hello World
- 2. Hello Mars
- 3. Foo bar

Considering *Foo Bar* the latest article from *foo* category, its content should be rendered in a page:

```
<title>
<content>
```

Where `<title>` is *Foo bar* and `<content>` is the post content.

How can I do this?

---

I'm struggling to implement the [@Pieter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31545/pieter-goosen)'s answer. I added these lines in `functions.php`:

```
function latest_post() {  
    $args = array(
       'posts_per_page' => 1, // we need only the latest post, so get that post only
       'cat' => '4' // Use the category id, can also replace with category_name which uses category slug
    );

    $str = "";
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach($posts as $post):
       $str = $str."<h2>".$post->title."</h2>";
       $str = $str."<p class='post-content-custom'>".$post->content."</p>";
    endforeach;

    return $str;
}

add_shortcode('latest_post', 'latest_post');
```

In the page I do:

```
[latest_post]
```

However, no error appears, but the post content doesn't appear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of `WP_Query` to call the lastest post from the category and display it. Have a look at the [category parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters). By default, `WP_Query` uses `post` as the post type and orders post by post date, so we can exclude that from the query. If you need something else, you can just define them in you arguments

You can basically try something like this

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1, // we need only the latest post, so get that post only
    'cat' => 'ID OF THE CATEGORY', // Use the category id, can also replace with category_name which uses category slug
    //'category_name' => 'SLUG OF FOO CATEGORY,
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args);

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();        
        //Your template tags and markup like:
        the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

This should provide you with a base, you can modify, customize and use it as you like. If you are unsure of the parameters and usage, check out the [`WP_Query` codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for assistance

### EDIT

I'm really not sure why you decided to reinvent the wheel and to go with `get_posts` where as I have showed you a working example of how to use `WP_Query`.  Your use of `get_posts` in conjuction with the [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) properties is completely wrong

- The `WP_Post` properties is unfiltered, so the output from this is totally unfiltered and will not look the same as the output from the template tags like `the_title()` or `the_content()`. You have to use the appropriate filters on those properties
- `title` and `content` is invalid properties of `WP_POST`. The other answer is completely wrong. It is `post_title` and `post_content`
- You can make use of the template tags as normal by just using `setup_postdata( $post );` and then just using `wp_reset_postdata()` afterwards

You can try the following

```
function latest_post() {  
    $args = array(
       'posts_per_page' => 1, // we need only the latest post, so get that post only
       'cat' => '4' // Use the category id, can also replace with category_name which uses category slug
    );

    $str = "";
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach($posts as $post):
       $str = $str."<h2>". apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title) ."</h2>";
       $str = $str."<p class='post-content-custom'>". apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ) ."</p>";
    endforeach;

    return $str;
}

add_shortcode('latest_post', 'latest_post');
```

Comment: Where should I add this code? This is still unclear to me...

Comment: You need to add it in your template where you need to display this post. Not to be rude or ugly, but we expect you to at least know the basics. :-)

Comment: See my edit. From what I see the size of the array is `1` which is expected, however I don't why the function doesn't return the expected result. Can you check the code (and maybe adding a working version in your answer)? Thanks!

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:::

```
 $args = array(
        'post_type' => '__post_type__',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC'

        );

$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($posts as $post):
 echo $post->ID;
 echo $post->title;
 echo $post->content;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Where shuold I add this? In the page content (editing in the text mode)?

Comment: in the template, template part or functions file if you are using shortcuts

Comment: Can you edit your post with the complete steps how to integrate this? I'm not the best in PHP, but following the steps should work.